# EntityType has no key defined error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

**Controller:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcApplication1.Models;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class studentsController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /students/

        public ActionResult details()
        {
            int id = 16;
            studentContext std = new studentContext();
           student first = std.details.Single(m => m.RollNo == id);
            return View(first);
        }

    }
}
```

**DbContext Model:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class studentContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<student> details { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    [Table("studentdetails")]
    public class student
    {
        public int RollNo;
        public string Name;
        public string Stream;
        public string Div;
    }
}
```

**Database table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[studentdetails](
    [RollNo] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Stream] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Div] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
```

**In global.asax.cs**

```
Database.SetInitializer<MvcApplication1.Models.studentContext>(null);
```

The above code lists all the classes I am working on. Upon running my application am receiving the error:

> "One or more validation errors were detected during model generation" along with "Entity type has no key defined".

Comment: Check the repository file. All the solutions in this page are amazing but in my case, I did everything right but forgot to declare the table as DbSet and add it to the modelbuilder.configurations.

Comment: In my case, I pointed the code to another db and the table was missing from db

Answer (score 194, accepted):

The Model class should be changed to :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    [Table("studentdetails")]
    public class student
    {
        [Key]
        public int RollNo { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Stream { get; set; }

        public string Div { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: my code worked (without `[Key]`) until I change the data types (I changed them to `unsigned`) and only byte works is there a reason I can't use `unsigned` values?

Comment: Entity Framework does not support unsigned integers http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896317(v=vs.100).aspx#UnsignedIntsUnsupported

Comment: And in case you are using it as a model in MVC, don't forget to rebuild!

Comment: Lots of different things can cause this error.  In my case, I mistakenly marked my "Id" field "private" instead of "public" (a habit from Java/JPA).  Larry Raymond's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29427325/421195) below is arguably the "best" reply to this question.  It lists most of the common scenarios behind "EntityType has no key defined error".

Answer (score 106):

1. Make sure public members of student class are defined as **properties** w/ `{get; set;}` (yours are public **variables** - a common mistake).
2. Place a `[Key]` annotation on top of your chosen property.

Comment: This was my problem. Thanks.  I was implementing an interface which only requires a getter for ID

Answer (score 91):

There are several reasons this can happen.  Some of these I found [here](https://gilesey.wordpress.com/tag/entitytype-has-no-key-defined/), others I discovered on my own.

- If the property is named something other than `Id`, you need to add the `[Key]` attribute to it.
- The key needs to be a property, not a field.
- The key needs to be `public`
- The key needs to be a CLS-compliant type, meaning unsigned types like `uint`, `ulong` etc. are not allowed.
- This error can also be caused by [configuration mistakes](https://gilesey.wordpress.com/2013/05/05/error-message-system-data-entity-edmentitytype-entitytype-blah-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entitytype/#comment-5142).

Comment: I have also found that the key property has to be read-write. I got OP's error when I had a getter and no setter on the ID property.

Comment: @JohnFx is absolutely correct. Resharper removed `private set` from some properties during a cleanup. The result was the "EntityType has no key defined error". So beware of cleanup tools removing necessary code.

Comment: In my case, I used some unrelated name to mention the Id of the class. Changing that as mentioned in your solution solved my problem. Thankyou :)

Comment: If you use any property like `ID` , `Id` , `ClassNameID`, `ClassNameId` you need not have to use `[Key] attribute`

Comment: Totally random, but when it happened to me, it was because my DataContext class was referencing the wrong class.  e.g. public DbSet<Payment> Payments { get; set; }   <-- Payment referenced a different class with the same name (oops).  If everything about your class seems correct, make sure this isn't your problem.

Answer (score 25):

i know that this post is late but
this solution helped me:

```
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
```

added [Column(Order = 0)]
after [Key] 
can be added by increment by 1:

```
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int RoleIdName { get; set; }
```

etc...

Comment: This did the trick for me. I had [Key] already but adding the order solved it.

Answer (score 20):

In my case, I was getting the error when creating an "MVC 5 Controller with view, using Entity Framework".

I just needed to Build the project after creating the Model class and didn't need to use the [Key] annotation.

Comment: Yes - 'Next, build the project. The Web API scaffolding uses reflection to find the model classes, so it needs the compiled assembly.' taken from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-2)

Comment: Exactly. Only "build" works, and none of the other previous answers does! I tried quite many ways and finally I built it and it worked! Then I came here and found this answer, which is the correct answer.

Comment: great. this was my case, after build all gets solved

Comment: Yes.... THANKS .... Strange this is an issue in a new updated VS2019 :D

Answer (score 10):

Using the [key] didn't work for me but using an id property does it.
I just add this property in my class.

```
public int id {get; set;}
```

Comment: It needs to be `[Key]`, but a property called "`id`" will also work.

Comment: public int Id { get; set; } or                                                                                        
                      [key] ^ public int Id1 { get; set; }

Answer (score 7):

The object must contain a field which will be used as the `Primary Key`, if you have a field named `Id` then this will by default be the primary key of the object to which Entity Framework will link to.

Otherwise, you should add the `[Key]` attribute above that field you wanna use as the `Primary Key`, and you'll also need to add the namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`:

```
public class myClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51180941/7003760

Comment: Thanks! Adding the System.ComponentModel.Annotations Nuget package to our Unit Tests project fixed this error for me. I was calling DbMigrator Update and it was failing even though our Domain project with our models and DbContext had the Nuget reference. *Both* projects need it.

Answer (score 5):

Additionally Remember, Don't forget to add ***public*** keyword like this

```
[Key] 
int RoleId { get; set; } //wrong method
```

you must use Public keyword like this

```
[Key] 
public int RoleId { get; set; } //correct method
```

Comment: This is what pointed me in the right direction, I had it as a field (no get/set declared).  Changed to a property and all good.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The reason why EF framework prompt 'no key' is that EF framework needs a primary key in database. To declaratively tell EF which property the key is, you add a `[Key]` annotation. Or, the quickest way, add an `ID` property. Then, the EF framework will take `ID` as the primary key by default.

Comment: What happens if the database has more than one field suffixed with ID? On regeneration I lose the Key attribute.

Comment: If you're generating the code from the DB, one of the columns in the table should be the table's primary Key.

Comment: Regarding "editing" generated code, it's almost always generated as a `partial` class. You can create a second file as a `partial` class with the same name, and add the property again with the `[Key]` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use key attribute all the time. Make sure the mapping file properly addressed the key

```
this.HasKey(t => t.Key);
this.ToTable("PacketHistory");
this.Property(p => p.Key)
            .HasColumnName("PacketHistorySK");
```

**and don't forget to add the mapping in the Repository's OnModelCreating**

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PacketHistoryMap());
```

Answer (score 1):

All is right but in my case i have two class like this

```
namespace WebAPI.Model
{
   public class ProductsModel
{ 
        [Table("products")]
        public class Products
        {
            [Key]
            public int slno { get; set; }

            public int productId { get; set; }
            public string ProductName { get; set; }

            public int Price { get; set; }
}
        }
    }
```

After deleting the upper class it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the model was fine. It was because I had 2 **different versions** of entity framework. One version for the web project and another one for the common project which contains the models.

I just had to **consolidate the nuget packages**.

[image]

Enjoy!

Comment: What do you mean by "consolidate the nuget packages"? I've never heard of this....

Answer (score 0):

I too solved this issue in my own project by solving this particular line in my code.
I added the following.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

After realizing my mistake I then went and changed it to

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

This further ensures that the field named "Id" increments in value each time a new row is inserted in the database