# EntityType no keys defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, key, identity

I'm creating an app where users log in via Facebook oAuth and then set up a list of songs. I am getting the following error message:

```
BandFinderCsharp.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

BandFinderCsharp.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.

IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
```

---

### The error message is occurring within my SongsController:

```
`namespace BandFinder.Controllers.Bread
{
    public class SongsController : Controller
    {
        private SongDBContext db = new SongDBContext();

        // GET: Songs
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Songs.ToList()); <--- This is where the error occurs
        }

        // GET: Songs/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(long? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Song song = db.Songs.Find(id);
            if (song == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(song);
        }

        // GET: Songs/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Songs/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,UserId,BandId,Title,Artist,Genre,ListId,CreatedOn")] Song song)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                song.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                db.Songs.Add(song);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(song);
        }

        // GET: Songs/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(long? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Song song = db.Songs.Find(id);
            if (song == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(song);
        }

        // POST: Songs/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,UserId,BandId,Title,Artist,Genre,ListId,CreatedOn")] Song song)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(song).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(song);
        }

        // GET: Songs/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(long? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Song song = db.Songs.Find(id);
            if (song == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(song);
        }

        // POST: Songs/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(long id)
        {
            Song song = db.Songs.Find(id);
            db.Songs.Remove(song);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}`
```

The thing I don't understand is, this controller has nothing to do with the IdentityUser code..

This is my ApplicationUser Model:

```
namespace BandFinderCsharp.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ApplicationUser()
        {
            CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            this.ProfileImage  = new byte[0];
            this.facebookImage = new byte[0];
        }

        public byte[] facebookImage { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(32)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(32)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public byte[] ProfileImage { get; set; }

        //public virtual ICollection<Instrument> Instruments { get; set; }
        //public virtual ICollection<Song> Songs { get; set; }
        //public virtual ICollection<Band> Bands { get; set; }

        public string Zipcode { get; set; }

        [Index]
        public float Longitude { get; set; }

        [Index]
        public float Latitude { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        //////////////

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Why am I getting an error referring to Identity models from the songs controller? There should be no correlation between the two at this point.

The **IdentityUser** class is a built in .NET class which I don't believe I'm able to edit:

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Default EntityFramework IUser implementation
    public class IdentityUser : IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>, IUser, IUser<string>
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Constructor which creates a new Guid for the Id
        public IdentityUser();
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Constructor that takes a userName
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   userName:
        public IdentityUser(string userName);
    }
}
```

**IdentityUserLogin**

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Entity type for a user's login (i.e. facebook, google)
    public class IdentityUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<string>
    {
        public IdentityUserLogin();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the model class for `IdentityUserLogins` and `IdentityUserRole`? Are all of their public members defined as properties? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203492

Comment: @Lukas I have provided the model classes.

Answer (score 4):

If the `ApplicationUser` class is the object you're looking to save in the Data Base, then it must contain a field named `Id` which is by default the primary key of the object to which Entity Framework is linking to.

Your Object should look like:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Or if you want to set a different property as the primary key for the object, you should add the `[Key]` attribute above that field - and you'll also need to add the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your entities, I am missing the [Key] attribute that defines the fields for the primary key.

Look at this question, first answer:
[EntityType 'Category' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862013/entitytype-category-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entitytype)

Comment: I added: [Key] public override string Id { get; set; } to my 'ApplicationUser' Model. That has not fixed it.

Comment: I am inheriting from 'IdentityUser' and cannot change that class