# MVC CRUD not appearing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have been new to asp and I have been following this tutorial

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ChahA1Hl-U
```

I have not been able to generate create, update , insert and delete  options.
My model is as follows:

```
     using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApplication3.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {

        [key]
        public string  CustomerCode { get; set; }

        public string CusomerName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

When I tried to create controller for the view,I get an error as
[image of error here](https://imagebin.ca/v/3dNRt5n03ffQ)
As I have key already defined, I am not getting what the error is saying. Thanks a lot for suggestion and help.

Comment: it is obvious that ur customer need a primary key, and +, ur question is not well defined

Comment: I have the key defined for Customer as
[key]
        public string  CustomerCode { get; set; }

Comment: Have a look at this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29427325/3814721).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EntityType has no key defined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203492/entitytype-has-no-key-defined-error)

Comment: Does your code compile? What I see is that in your pasted code you use "[key]", it is lowercase and it should be "[Key]"...